# Yahoo OAuth with gtm-oauth for Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, oauth, yahoo

Has anyone successfully used [gtm-oauth](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/) to authenticate to Yahoo for a desktop Mac App?  I'm able to authenticate to Twitter using this library and I feel that I've made the appropriate updates for Yahoo OAuth but I consistently get a 401 error when I start the request and the view controller is not shown.

I've updated the values in the OAuthSample project as such:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token"];
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token"];
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth"];
NSString *scope = @"https://api.login.yahoo.com";
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo's OAuth server does not expect display name or scope parameters.

To use GTMOAuth with Yahoo's OAuth 1 server, set the scope and the display name to nil, like

windowController = [[[GTMOAuthWindowController alloc] initWithScope:nil
    language:nil
    requestTokenURL:requestURL
    authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
    accessTokenURL:accessURL
    authentication:auth
    appServiceName:kYahooKeychainItemName
    resourceBundle:nil] autorelease];

[auth setDisplayName:nil];

Also, be sure that the auth callback URL matches the URL registered with Yahoo.